# increment figure source names

Tags: graphics, animations

In our childhood, probably all of us made some drawings on layered sheets of paper in order to make an animation.

[edit: This is to be added to an existing document, next to the page number for example.]

To do such an page-by-page animation in a LaTeX document of 123 pages (e.g.), I would like to include images named from "image001" to "image123" in successive pages, so that:

- page 1 includes "image001"
- page 2 includes "image002"
- ...
- page 123 includes "image123".

A way to do this is would be to use a command of the form:

```
\includegraphics[]{\BASENAME + \PAGENUMBER + \INCREMENT}

% \BASENAME: path of folder + beginning of name
% \PAGENUMBER: page number
% \INCREMENT: number of the first page to have an image (minus one)
```

but I do not know how to implement such a feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be simpler solutions, but it is possible to add a sequence of images in the header doing so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp} 

\newcommand{\startImageNum}{15} % first included image is image15
\newcommand{\fileExtNumDef}{\FPeval\fileExtNum{round(\thepage + \startImageNum:0)}}

% define the right header:

\rhead[]{\fileExtNumDef\fileExtNum~\includegraphics[width=3cm]{image\fileExtNum}}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

It is possible to change the header anywhere by redefining rhead.

This solution requires fancyhdr and fp packages which i am already using.

Answer (score 4):

Use a whiledo-loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %remove if you have the images
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\increment{1}
\whiledo{\increment < 50}
 {Image \ifnum\increment<10 0\fi\increment: 
  \includegraphics{image\ifnum\increment<10 0\fi\increment}\newpage
  \edef\increment{\the\numexpr\increment +1}%
 }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I might no have been clear enough: I would like to add the images in an existing document, for example next to the page number. Your suggestion creates a new page for each figure. But your answer helped me understand the structure I should use. I will probably post a solution soon.

Comment: @anderstood: If the graphic is in the header or footer definition something like `\includegraphics{image\arabic{page}}` should work (you perhaps need some additional code to handle leading zeros).

Comment: @Ultrike Fischer: I'd like to post my solution, based on your answer. How can I do this without not accepting your solution ?

Comment: @anderstood: You can edit your question. Or write a answer.