# How I could add an image in the bottom of pages of my document

Tags: graphics, header-footer

[image]

Hello! In the picture you can see the bottom of pages 2-7 of one document that I found. I would like to apply the same format in my document and I would like your help. As you can see the document consists of three different images - turbines in different position - (page 3,5,7) and this is repeated till the end.

Generally, how I could place an image in the bottom of my page like in this document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You might find the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38751/) useful.

Comment: have a look at the `fancyhdr` package

Comment: Link that could be useful here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129706/increment-figure-source-names

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two main packages used for defining page styles are [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and [`titleps`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps); the former is considered the classic package for footer/headers; the former is newer but equally powerful.

Each one of these packages has its own interface to produce headers/footers (examples below illustrate some of the available commands); please refer to the packages documentation for further information.

In the examples below I show how to produce the desired footers with each of those packages; in both cases, [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) was used to draw the moving windmill; the windmill moves automatically, according to the value for `\thepage` mod 3.

Of course, instead of a TikZ picture, you can include existing images using the standard `\includegraphics` command from the `graphicx` package.

One possibility using [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) to define the footer.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[inner=30pt,outer=6cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{intcalc}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand\WindMill{%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{page}}{3}=1\relax
  \def\Angle{70}
\else
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{page}}{3}=2\relax
  \def\Angle{30}
\else
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{page}}{3}=0\relax
  \def\Angle{-10}
\fi\fi\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw 
  ([xshift=-80pt]current page.south east) --
  ++(3pt,80pt) -- ++(2pt,0pt) coordinate (center) -- ++(3pt,-100pt);
\draw[rotate=\Angle,fill=white] (center.\Angle) rectangle ++(1.7cm,3pt);
\draw[rotate=\Angle-120,fill=white] (center.\Angle-120) rectangle ++(1.7cm,3pt);
\draw[rotate=\Angle+120,fill=white] (center.\Angle+120) rectangle ++(1.7cm,3pt);
\node[draw,fill=white,circle=inner sep=2pt] at ([xshift=-1pt]center) (circle) {}; 
\draw 
  ([xshift=-10pt]circle.west) -- ++(-\paperwidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyfoot[OR]{\WindMill}
\fancyfoot[EL]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \draw ([yshift=80pt]current page.south west) -- ++(\paperwidth,0);
    \node[font=\small\scshape,anchor=north west] at ([yshift=80pt,xshift=30pt]current page.south west) {Wind Energy -- TU Delft};
  }
}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

An image of the footer for pages 1 to 6:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And some zoomed individual images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, the same style produced using the [`titleps`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps) package:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[inner=30pt,outer=6cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{intcalc}

\newcommand\WindMill{%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{page}}{3}=1\relax
  \def\Angle{70}
\else
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{page}}{3}=2\relax
  \def\Angle{30}
\else
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{page}}{3}=0\relax
  \def\Angle{-10}
\fi\fi\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw 
  ([xshift=-80pt]current page.south east) --
  ++(3pt,80pt) -- ++(2pt,0pt) coordinate (center) -- ++(3pt,-100pt);
\draw[rotate=\Angle,fill=white] (center.\Angle) rectangle ++(1.7cm,3pt);
\draw[rotate=\Angle-120,fill=white] (center.\Angle-120) rectangle ++(1.7cm,3pt);
\draw[rotate=\Angle+120,fill=white] (center.\Angle+120) rectangle ++(1.7cm,3pt);
\node[draw,fill=white,circle=inner sep=2pt] at ([xshift=-1pt]center) (circle) {}; 
\draw 
  ([xshift=-10pt]circle.west) -- ++(-\paperwidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newpagestyle{windmill}
{\setfoot[%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \draw ([yshift=80pt]current page.south west) -- ++(\paperwidth,0);
    \node[font=\small\scshape,anchor=north west] at ([yshift=80pt,xshift=30pt]current page.south west) {Wind Energy -- TU Delft};
  }
][\thepage][]{}{\thepage}{\WindMill}
}
\pagestyle{windmill}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

It has been requested in a comment to lower the elements a little:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[inner=30pt,outer=6cm,bottom=3.5cm,footskip=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{intcalc}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand\WindMill{%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{page}}{3}=1\relax
  \def\Angle{70}
\else
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{page}}{3}=2\relax
  \def\Angle{30}
\else
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{page}}{3}=0\relax
  \def\Angle{-10}
\fi\fi\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw 
  ([xshift=-80pt]current page.south east) --
  ++(3pt,30pt) -- ++(2pt,0pt) coordinate (center) -- ++(3pt,-100pt);
\draw[rotate=\Angle,fill=white] (center.\Angle) rectangle ++(1cm,3pt);
\draw[rotate=\Angle-120,fill=white] (center.\Angle-120) rectangle ++(1cm,3pt);
\draw[rotate=\Angle+120,fill=white] (center.\Angle+120) rectangle ++(1cm,3pt);
\node[draw,fill=white,circle,inner sep=3pt] at ([xshift=-1pt]center) (circle) {}; 
\draw 
  ([xshift=-10pt]circle.west) -- ++(-\paperwidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyfoot[OR]{\WindMill}
\fancyfoot[EL]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \draw ([yshift=30pt]current page.south west) -- ++(\paperwidth,0);
    \node[font=\small\scshape,anchor=north west] at ([yshift=30pt,xshift=30pt]current page.south west) {Wind Energy -- TU Delft};
  }
}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful and detailed answer! I just implemented and it works fine! I would like to decrease the size of the image and I would like to put the  line 1 cm lower as well. Which of the following should I change??

Comment: Again the size of the windmill have not changed. Which is the part of the code that I can modify the size??

Comment: @ChristosTsouknidas answer updated. Basically, you modify some of the lengths used in the definition of `\WindMill`. Thanks for accepting the answer :)

Comment: Hi again. I want to have the bottom line and the wind mill in blue colour instant of black. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the packages [mentioned by Gonzalo in his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162038/) there is at least one other couple of packages provided by KOMA-Script, *but not restricted to be used only with KOMA-Script classes*: the legacy `scrpage2` (which has itself an obsolete predecessor `scrpage`) and its recent successor `scrlayer-scrpage`. If you are not forced to work with an outdated KOMA-Script (because your admins are too lazy to update or similar issues) you should use `scrlayer-scrpage`, it’s downwards compatible and does provide more fetatures.

Below you can see the code developed by Gonzalo, but adapted to `scrlayer-scrpage`. I intentionally left the lines with `fancyhdr` code in, so one can see, that the shift from this package is not very hard. One thing I wanted to show is, that there is by default a plain pagestyle companion, that can be changed in the optional arguments for head and foot style macros. I did this and added a page with this plain style. This page style is important for title pages and classes with chapters.

BTW when one would additionally load the package `scrextend`, more of the useful KOMA-Script features could be used with other classes, as well.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[inner=30pt,outer=6cm,bottom=3.5cm,footskip=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{intcalc}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\newcommand\WindMill{%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{page}}{3}=1\relax
  \def\Angle{70}
\else
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{page}}{3}=2\relax
  \def\Angle{30}
\else
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{page}}{3}=0\relax
  \def\Angle{-10}
\fi\fi\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw
  ([xshift=-80pt]current page.south east) --
  ++(3pt,30pt) -- ++(2pt,0pt) coordinate (center) -- ++(3pt,-100pt);
\draw[rotate=\Angle,fill=white] (center.\Angle) rectangle ++(1cm,3pt);
\draw[rotate=\Angle-120,fill=white] (center.\Angle-120) rectangle ++(1cm,3pt);
\draw[rotate=\Angle+120,fill=white] (center.\Angle+120) rectangle ++(1cm,3pt);
\node[draw,fill=white,circle,inner sep=3pt] at ([xshift=-1pt]center) (circle) {}; 
\draw
  ([xshift=-10pt]circle.west) -- ++(-\paperwidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

%\fancyhf{}
\clearpairofpagestyles
%\fancyfoot[OR]{\WindMill}
\rofoot[\WindMill]{\WindMill}
%\fancyfoot[EL]{%
\lefoot[% different definition for plain page style
  {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \node[font=\small\scshape,anchor=north west] at ([yshift=30pt,xshift=30pt]current page.south west) {Wind Energy -- TU Delft};
  }}%
]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \draw ([yshift=30pt]current page.south west) -- ++(\paperwidth,0);
    \node[font=\small\scshape,anchor=north west] at ([yshift=30pt,xshift=30pt]current page.south west) {Wind Energy -- TU Delft};
  }
}
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\cfoot[\thepage]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-35]

\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain.scrheadings}
\mbox{}
% needed to produce an empty page, else one the first "\newpage" command would be swallowed
\newpage

\lipsum[36-50]
\end{document}
```